# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img') React

Tags: reactjs

Please Guys i need Help, i got this error when i am compiling the code. i put items in a file data.js and it is working for others products but for this One i don't know what i am missing.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorderOutlined';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCartOutlined'

const Product = ({items}) => {
    return (
        <Container>
        
            <Circle />
            
            <Image src={items.img} />
            
            <Info>
                <Icon>
                    <ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon />
                </Icon>
                <Icon>
                    <SearchIcon />
                </Icon>
                <Icon>
                    <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
                </Icon>
            </Info>
    </Container>
    )
}

export default Product;



const Container = styled.div`
    flex: 1;
    margin: 5px;
`;
 
const Circle = styled.div``;

const Image = styled.img``;

const Info = styled.div``;

const Icon = styled.div``;
```

Comment: Did you check your `items` property for a null or undefined `img`?

Comment: Is the `items` prop being passed correctly(Check for spelling errors in the parent component). Check the parent component where the prop is being added to the child. Try something like this there `items={items.img}`. Also make sure that you have an img property available.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for the existence of the image before you send it to `src`

```
items && test.img ? test.img : "https://www.example.com/example.png"
```

So just add it to your styled image:

```
 <Image src={items && test.img ? test.img : "https://www.example.com/example.png"} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if your items props get correctly image or img source. For that You have to give that component from where you send items as props.

Here you can check if your items has img property. For that console the items in useEffect.

```
import {useEffect} from "react"

const Product = ({items}) => {
    const useEffect = () => {
      console.log(items)
    }
    return (
        <Container>
        
            <Circle />
            
            <Image src={items.img} />
            
            <Info>
                <Icon>
                    <ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon />
                </Icon>
                <Icon>
                    <SearchIcon />
                </Icon>
                <Icon>
                    <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
                </Icon>
            </Info>
    </Container>
    )
}

export default Product;
```

In that way you can confirm your items has a img property.

Comment: thanks buddy. i will check immediatly

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible causes of your error, either img is not a key in your data.js or a you are incorrectly including a component where you have your Product component with item props in the tree.
Solution 1: Check if you have img as a key in data.js.

```
<Image src = { item && item.img ? item.img : "https://sometestimage.com/test.jpg" } />
```

If you get the test image rendered, then the key img is there inside your data.js but either the component containing Product component isn't correctly included in the tree or you're including the Product component instead of its mother component.
Solution 2: Check how you include/import both Product component and its mother component in the component tree.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently following the same tutorial and got the same error .

In my case it was home page auto import importing Product from other component page so you can not get the Images you should check your home and replace:

```
import Product from '../components/Product'
```

to

```
import Product from '../components/Products'
```